# Static initializers and Constant Wrapper Variables

Tags: java

Here is a quick snippet of code. I can relate to JLS section 12.4 and 12.5 for the class loading and initialization process.  the class will only be loaded if you are accessing a static variable of the class which is not a constant or may be access the static method. In my case, i am declaring the  variable as final, remove the final attribute, and check class will be loaded and static initializer will run. Below is the modified code

```
class staticFinalDemo1  {    
    //static final int var= 100;    
    static int var= 100;    

        static final void test()  {    
           System.out.println("Static Final Method Test");    
    }    
    static  {    
               System.out.println("Static Initializer");    
    }    
}    


class staticFinalDemo2 {    

        public static void main(String[] args)   {    

            System.out.println(staticFinalDemo1.var);    
            //staticFinalDemo1.test();    
        }    
    }
```

Now my point is if i modify the final statement and replace it with following statement.

```
 static final Integer var= 100;
```

The static initializer gets loaded. Now this variable is a constant. Why it is loading the
static initializer in this case? Is it because i am using a wrapper object and its instance
will be initialized when i refer it in the class for usage? Please clarify this concept.

Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this variable is not a compile-time constant. A constant can only be of primitive type or of type String. Integer does not qualify.

See [JLS §15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28):

> A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following: [...]

Answer (score 2):

Non constant fields are initialized in constructors. Static fields in static constructors and instance fields in instance constructors. For your case, try making variable of type Integer and view bytecode:

```
class staticFinalDemo1 {
  static java.lang.Integer var;

  static {};
    Code:
       0: bipush        100
       2: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       5: putstatic     #6                  // Field var:Ljava/lang/Integer;
       8: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      11: ldc           #7                  // String Static Initializer
      13: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      16: return
}
```

on lines 0 - 5, value to an var field is assigned. bipush loads 100 to the stack, invokestatic   creates Integer object and putstatic saves it to a static variable. In case of int type these lines are absent. Value already exists in constant pool.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It makes terrific sense. I understand the point now.

Comment: Welcome, use "javap -c staticFinalDemo1" to view bytecode. It has comments, which make things pretty clear, even without reading Java Virtual machine Specification.

Answer (score 1):

Big 'I' integer is not a constant, it's a reference type to an Integer object.  In java you may use Integer and int interchangeably, but the actual value is different.