# Initialization of static variables in a class which has a private constructor

Tags: java, static, jvm

Suppose the following class

```
class A{
  public final static int num = 7;
  public final static A instance = new A();
  private A(){}
}

class TestA{
  public static void main(String args[]){
     System.out.print(A.num);
  }
}
```

In this scenario when is `num` and `instance` initialized and when is class A loaded in the JVM?. I had the understanding that the JVM loads a class when it is initialized, correct me if I'm wrong. As the class A has a private constructor it cannot be initialized externally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "And instance is called by A.instance multiple times."?

Comment: sorry, just edited my post. If either num or instance is called by multiple classes (not simultaneously).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17707504/2031799 - may be this can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are initialized when the class is first loaded by the class loader, which is typically when you first use a class either statically or by instantiating some objects. Imports don't count as using a class. They are ignored by the compiler until you actually do something with the class.

You can customize the initialization with a static initializer block in the class. This works very much like a constructor, except it gets executed when the class is loaded and before the first constructor call.

```
class Foo {
  public static final String FOO;

  {
    FOO="helloworld";
  }
}
```

Comment: So the order would be;
1- The variable 'instance' as TestA calls A.num
2- Class A through 'new A()'
2- Variable 'num',    
am I right?

Comment: yeah class loader loads class when you access A.num, it initializes A and ends up calling A().

Answer (score 1):

It is executed when class is loaded.  A class gets loaded whenever it is constructed or its static variables/methods are accessed.

Comment: Imports have nothing to do with this. They don't even exist at runtime. Only in the source code.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for that input. I amended the answer.

Comment: It's still wrong. A class are not loaded when another class that references it get loaded. It's loaded lazily, when needed. i.e. if a method in class A needs class B but is never called, the class B will never be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, when the class is loaded, the static block and static variables are initialized because they belong to the class.

Answer (score 1):

object `A.instance` is initialized at the first reference used in the code, class `A` is initialized when it is found as a dependency of another class to be loaded

Answer (score 1):

In fact when you use `A.num` it won't initialize at all, because the compile substitutes the constants, and everywhere `A.num` is used, the compiler puts `7` instead.

You can decompile a compiled class to see this.

But `A.instance` is initialized when `A` is loaded by class-loader.

Comment: If you saying that 'instance' is initialized when 'A' is loaded, when would 'A' be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

As num and instance are static data of class. Static means somethings is shared between all the instances of the class. And all static data is loaded when ever your class is loaded in JVM. You dont need to wait for instance creation for accessing static data. SO in your case as soon as you run the class num and instance will be loaded in the JVM at runtime.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

An example of a standard Java class that does just this is [java.lang.Math](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java)

Since it is a utility class, not intended to be instantiated, the constructor is private, yet it contains constants for E, PI, etc...